# How to get meaningful help pages for aws CLI subcommands like `aws s3 cp`?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface, aws-cli, manpage

I'm trying to figure out what options there are for the `aws s3 cp` CLI command but neither of the following work.

When I use `--help` or `-h` I get the following useless CLI output that doesn't say anything about `s3`, let alone `s3 cp` subcommands:

```
$ aws s3 cp --help
     
usage: aws [-h] [--profile PROFILE] [--debug]

options:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit
  --profile PROFILE
  --debug
```

Neither can I find man pages using `man aws`, `man aws-s3` or `man aws-s3-cp`.

I know I can find the docs online: https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/cp.html but how do I get similar information directly in my terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unintuitive answer is to type `help` without the `--`. When you type:

```bash
aws s3 cp help
```

you get the appropriate man page to open in a pager:

```
CP()                                                                      CP()



NAME
       cp -

DESCRIPTION
       Copies a local file or S3 object to another location locally or in S3.

SYNOPSIS
            cp
          <LocalPath> <S3Uri> or <S3Uri> <LocalPath> or <S3Uri> <S3Uri>
          [--dryrun]
          [--quiet]
          [--include <value>]
          [--exclude <value>]
...
```

I don't quite understand why aws decided to not accept the nearly universal standard `-h` for subcommands. Maybe someone can enlighten me in the comments.

Adding `help` works everywhere, even on a raw `aws` as `aws help` which again opens a manpage. Strange that this `help` addition is not listed when passing `-h`.

Comment: Opened an issue to point out that `-h` provides lacking information: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/7648

Comment: There is a [10 year old issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/303) for this.  I'd love to see it change, but I suspect it won't.  Personally, I'd love if it they actually made the links in sections like `aws glacier help` where it says `What is Amazon S3 Glacier` be actual links, instead of useless references to things I don't think you can even load in the CLI.

Comment: This is a bit of a quirk in how AWS CLI is generated and what `aws s3` actually is. Where as almost all CLI commands match their associated API (e.g `aws ec2`) and produce somewhat useful information generated from the API, the `aws s3` command is not generated from the API. Instead the actual API can be accessed by `aws s3api`. The `aws s3` application is a helper on top of the `s3api` that tries to make it a bit more "POSIX" like with commands like `ls`.

Comment: @Mark hmm, how is this a quirk of `aws s3`? When I type `aws ec2 -h` I get the same useless standard help, same as `aws -h`. Does `man` work for any of them?

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer, no you either have to use `--help` or `help`. All aws cli flags are prepended with `--` and are full words not single symbols. There doesn't appear to be a man page but `help` displays the equivalent. The flag `--help` displays the command summary.  You get no help with -h or --help for `aws ec2` because there is no `ec2` command. You would need something like `aws ec2 list-instances` or something. Using `aws ec2 help` will give you the possible sub-commands.

Comment: @Mark I'm still confused. `-h` and `--help` are treated equally by `aws` and all subcommands I've tried. Just the same useless snippet.  So the first sentence seems wrong (that you need to use `--help` not `-h`). `--help` only displays the same useless content as `-h`, try it out! Or are you on a different version? I'm on 2.9.

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer, ah got you. I think what is happening is that `--help` or `-h` (which seems to be the only single char flag) is a flag for `aws` and not for `aws <service> <subcommand>`. This is unfortunate and not very helpful.

Comment: @Mark Yes exactly! Now we're on the same page I think. As @AnonCoward pointed out above, there's already been a long standing issue about this. Would be great to add maybe a tiny little help text to the general `aws` command usage to point users to try `help` instead of `-h/--help`. See https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/303

Answer (score 1):

Try: `aws s3 cp help`

i.e. removing the dashes from `--help`